# Whose skull should/could I use?

Tags: rogue-trader, dark-heresy-1e

Being a Tech Priest in the Dark Heresy/Rogue Trader universe, my (personal) first and foremost need is to accrue Servo Skulls. I have already acquired one, and I am already lining up plans for another.

However... this second candidate for my posse is a Kroot.

Can I / should I use a Kroot skull for my next Servo Skull? Is that allowed in the lore?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Traditionally Servo skulls are made from those who are very loyal or very pious, and it is considered a great honour to serve the Emperor in death.

http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Servo-skull

I expect your average tech priest would consider using a Xenos to be blasphemy and tech-heresy.

If you are a rogue techpriest or a member of the Dark Mechanicus, then it would be totally fine.